# Quantum Mechanics - Eigenvalue and Eigenvector of a Matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quantum-mechanics

I'm attempting to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors from the following matrix :

\begin{pmatrix}
-3\cos\theta&\sqrt{3}\sin\theta e^{iφ}&0&0\\\sqrt{3}\sin\theta  e^{-iφ}&-\cos\theta&\sqrt{3}\sin\theta e^{iφ}&0\\0&\sqrt{3}\sin\theta  e^{-iφ}&\cos\theta&\sqrt{3}\sin\theta e^{iφ}\\0&0&\sqrt{3}\sin\theta  e^{-iφ}&3\cos\theta \end{pmatrix}

I can get as far as :

\begin{eqnarray}
-\left(3\cos\theta+λ\right)\left(\cos\theta+λ\right)\left[\left(\cos\theta-λ\right)\left(3\cos\theta-λ\right)-3\sin^2\theta\right]+\\
-4\sin^2\theta\left(3\cos\theta-λ\right)\left(3\cos\theta+λ\right)+\sqrt{3}\sin\theta e^{-iφ}\left[\left(\cos\theta-λ\right)\left(3\cos\theta -λ\right)-3\sin^2\theta\right]=0
\end{eqnarray}
However, the solution I'm provided with states that after some tedious algebraic manipulation I should arrive at :
\begin{eqnarray}
\left(\left(3\cos\theta-λ\right)\left(\cos\theta-λ\right)-3\sin^2\theta \right)\left(\left(3\cos\theta+λ\right)\left(\cos\left(\theta \right)+λ\right)-3\sin^2\theta \right)+
\\+4\sin^2\theta\left(3\cos\theta+λ\right)\left(3\cos\theta-λ\right)=0
\end{eqnarray}
I'm having difficulty figuring out the necessary algebra between these two steps, where I assume I need to eliminate $e^{-i\phi}$ with the help of Euler's formula, but I still hit a brick wall.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Figured it out. I didn't multiply by my initial coefficients, as shown below, which end up cancelling $e^{-i\phi}$ and with a bit of rearranging I get the desired result.

\begin{eqnarray}
\left(3cos\left(\theta\right)+λ\right)\{-\left(cos\left(\theta \right)-λ\right)\left[\left(3cos\left(\theta\right)-λ\right)\left(cos\left(\theta\right)-λ\right)-3sin^2\left(\theta \right)\right]-4sin^2\left(\theta\right)\left(3cos\left(\theta \right)-λ\right)\}+\sqrt{3}sin\left(\theta \right)e^{iϕ}\{\sqrt{3}sin\left(\theta \right)e^{-iϕ}\left[\left(3cos\left(\theta\right)-λ\right)\left(cos\left(\theta \right)-λ\right)-3sin^2\left(λ\right)\right]\}=0
\end{eqnarray}

Thanks for the assistance and pointing out my errors.

Comment: Does $g$ of the second equation plays the role of $\lambda$ of the first equation?

Comment: @levap Apologies, it does. I just corrected the equation.

Comment: Also, I guess you have a typo in the $3 \times 2$ entry of the matrix (it should have $e^{-i\varphi}$ instead of $e^{i \varphi}$) to make the matrix self-adjoint, which is consistent with the second equation. This should "eliminate" the complex factors, resulting in real eigenvalues.

Comment: Do you really mean to have $\cos(x)$  rather than $\cos(\theta)$ in two places?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Once again, I apologise. Sloppy work typing out the equations on my part. I've amended the equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first equation is not correct. If you plug $\theta = 0$, the matrix becomes $\operatorname{diag}(-3,-1,1,3)$ and so the characteristic equation should be $(\lambda - 3)(\lambda + 3)(\lambda - 1)(\lambda + 1) = 0$. This is indeed consistent with the second equation but from the first equation you get

$$ -(1 + \lambda)(1 - \lambda)(3 - \lambda) = 0 $$

so you have made an error somewhere in your calculation of the determinant.

Comment: You're right. Reducing the matrix while solving for the determinant I didn't multiply by the initial $\left(3cos\left(\theta\right)+λ\right)$. Really silly mistake ...
I've amended the equation my OP. Will try again ...

Comment: You still have an error somewhere because your $e^{-i \varphi}$ cannot be cancelled but the matrix has only real eigenvalues.

Comment: Updated my OP. Thanks again for your help. It's actually quite easy when you don't screw up the expansion of your determinant ...

Comment: You're welcome! :)